# retreaving data from a mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a mysql database which was created for a website using wordpress, when posting some text using wordpress it stores it on that database. When I try pulling this text using a php file, it returns null, but if I delete this text and write it in manually(no wordpress) it pulls it fine. is there anything specific i need to do in order to pull this text since it was created using wordpress? the structure of the table is as follows, field: post_content type: longtext. Thanks for the help

Code:

```
$query = "SELECT post_content FROM meiplay_posts WHERE post_type = 'portfolio'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    $output[] = $row;
print(json_encode($output));
```

Comment: What query are you running? What PHP code are you running?

Comment: $query="SELECT post_content FROM meiplay_posts WHERE post_type = 'portfolio'";
$result=mysql_query($query);
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
$output[]=$row;
print(json_encode($output));

Comment: I tried the quotes ('post_content') but all i get is "post_content":"post_content" i dont get the text. Also i added the extra code for the $result but i dont get any error messages

Comment: Are you sure you're connected to the db? Did you add error handling as Brendan Long suggested?

Comment: yea i added the code and yea im connected to the db!

Answer (score 1):

Add some error handling:

```
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

This will cause an error message to be printed if something goes wrong in `mysql_query`. Hopefully the error message will help.

Also, [the documentation for `mysql_query` says](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php):

> Use of this extension is discouraged. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

So I'd advise using the libraries that the PHP authors recommend.

Also:

```
$query = "SELECT post_content FROM meiplay_posts WHERE post_type = 'portfolio'";
```

Are your sure that columns with `post_type = 'portfolio'` exist? Try doing the select without the `WHERE` part and see if you get anything. Maybe it's slightly different, like `Portfolio` instead of `portfolio`?

Comment: yea I checked on that, if i edit the post_content field by entering something manually it works fine

Comment: @paul590 If you add something manually, then you're not selecting from the database, you're just retrieving the data you're giving it..

Comment: thats true, and im trying to use MYSQLi but no luck with that either

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress gives you a class that lets you run your queries on the database more easily.
Reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_a_Column

Try:

```
$result = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("SELECT `post_content` FROM `meiplay_posts` WHERE post_type = 'portfolio'")); 

if ($result) 
{
   echo $result->post_content;
   echo json_encode($result);
};
```

Comment: this is a good reference thanks! im trying the method you posted above but i keep getting this error: Fatal error: Call to a member function get_col() on a non-object in /homepages/17/d280020283/htdocs/meiplay/folder/index.php on line 8